# Disabling RepeatingAlarms does not work [Android platform]

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a hudge problem with disabling alarms form AlarmManager on Android.

I have read several articles and answers here
and no clue why my cancel() for alarm does not work.

I have even changed my code to this, with static variables... (and still does not work)
the code is stored in Utility.class other than the one which calls the method.

```
public class Utilities {
public static final int ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM = 770;

private static PendingIntent piStopMyApp;
private static Intent aiStopMyApp;
private static Context aContext;

public static boolean toggleAlarmToStopMyApp(Context context) {

    if(aContext == null){
        aContext = context;
    }

    if (aiStopMyApp == null) {
        aiStopMyApp = new Intent(aContext, MyAppServiceStop.class);
    }

    PendingIntent piStopMyAppCheck = PendingIntent.getService(aContext,
            ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM, aiStopMyApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) aContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (piStopMyApp == null) {
        piStopMyApp = PendingIntent.getService(aContext, ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM,
                      aiStopMyApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    if (piStopMyAppCheck == null) {

        SharedPreferences p = aContext.getSharedPreferences(
                Utilities.APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int h = p.getInt(Utilities.ALARM_STOP_H, 23);
        int m = p.getInt(Utilities.ALARM_STOP_M, 0);

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (isLoggingEnabled) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enable ALARM for STOP " + cal.toString());
        }

        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, piStopMyApp);

    } else {

        alarm.cancel(piStopMyApp);

        if (isLoggingEnabled) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disable ALARM for STOP = "
                + (PendingIntent.getService(aContext,
                            ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM,aiStopMyApp,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null));
        }

    }

    piStopMyAppCheck = null;

    return (PendingIntent.getService(aContext, ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM, aiStopMyApp,

            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}

}
```

and it simply does not work, enables alarm and cannot disable it :-(

button in other activity runs such code:

```
    boolean alarmUpStop  = Utilities.toggleAlarmToStopMyApp(getApplicationContext());
```

1) the first hit to the button above and Alarms are scheduled properly, logs shows service triggered

2) the second hit to the button and logs say that alarm was tried to disable but it wasn't disabled :-(

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried using media player for playing the alarm?

Comment: this alarm is intended to run a service which controls another one service :-) so it is not media related alarm :-)

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: added class declaration and now this is full code. In other activity there is button with action:  boolean state = toggleAlarmToStopMyApp(getApplicationContext()); nothing more related to toggling this alarm :-(

Comment: are you sure that this [alarm.cancel(piStopMyApp);] is in the right place?

Comment: till now I was :-) it is used when piStopMyAppCheck != null, so according to other articles, it is used when alarm with the same intent is set... here is LOG after running button when alarls are active: 11-09 12:04:01.141: D/MYAPP(18472): Disable ALARM for START = false
11-09 12:04:01.146: D/MYAPP(18472): Disable ALARM for STOP = false -> it proves that alarms were tried to cancel but with no success

Comment: i cant really see the problem haha, all i can suggest is you use media player its easier to control when a certain condition is met in the Service then trigger the alarm via media player.

Comment: I will work on it a little bit more because it suits my needs for 100% if it starts working :-)

Comment: someone will figure this out im sure, you just need to be patient haha, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the alarm is active by using:

```
PendingIntent.getService(aContext, ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM,aiStopMyApp,
                       PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null
```

Your comparison against `null` was just wrong. The documentation for `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` is incorrect. It returns `null` if there is no matching `PendingIntent`, otherwise it returns the matching `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work because of checking if alarm is running by using:
(PendingIntent.getService(aContext, ID_FOR_STOP_ALARM,aiStopMyApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null)

I just simply changed it to:

1) when runing alarm, I am storing alarmRunning = true in Prefs to know that alarm is active

2) when cancelling alarms I am setting alarmRunning = false in Prefs to know that alarm is  disabled

on boot I know the last state from Prefs and I can recreate alarms if necessary

This Workaround has flaws but works, it just assumes that when alarms is set, it has to be held by the system no matter what [till boot], but it shluld be so :-)

See you in next Qs.
V.